# Syntax of adding an action listener

Tags: java, swing, syntax, jbutton, actionlistener

When I enter the following code:

```
JButton aButton = new JButton("Button");
aButtin.addActionListener(this);
```

my IDE (NetBeans) highlights this as a leaking this statement.
Though there never seem to be any negative repercussions from using the statement as such, some docs that I have read indicate that the more proper method is to add the action listener as a new instance of an inner class that implements ActionListener.
What do NetBeans and these docs know that I don't?
What is really meant by a leaking this statement?
Are there negative repercussions that I am unaware of in the use of this in this way?

Comment: How is that opinion based? I was asking if there were technical advantages to one over the other! It wasn't asking for an opinion but a clarification as to why one method might be better than the other in a scenario where methods were reused.

Comment: It is opinion based; see my answer below. There is no specific advantage/disadvantage, nor is there a distinct correct answer - there is a way to write equivalent code in all of these cases. All possible answers to this question are based entirely on opinion and preference. It is like asking "What is the best color? What are its advantages?" -- If you truly believe that there is a quantitative "best" color then I suppose you would not realize that the question is opinion based, but in reality it is and the belief is incorrect.

Comment: All I wanted to know is why I've seen it written two different ways and for what purpose. I wasn't asking who preferred what method. I wanted to know what the implications for choosing one over the other might be. I have absolutely no idea why that is so offensive.

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn what a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is.

Comment: So, if I had worded the question: "Why use A other that B?" that would have been fine?

Comment: If you had worded the question, "I am working on a program with the following code, and I was using method A but having problem XYZ. I've tried to solve problem XYZ by using method B instead, but I'm still having issues. What am I doing wrong?" then it would have been fine.

Comment: Some subjective questions are allowed, but “subjective” does not mean “anything goes”. All subjective questions are expected to be constructive. What does that mean? Constructive subjective questions:

inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”
tend to have long, not short, answers
have a constructive, fair, and impartial tone
invite sharing experiences over opinions
insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references
are more than just mindless social fun

Comment: @JasonC I don't think your argument is quite fair - the question does have some merit. For example, `new ButtonPress()` will use more space if you `addActionListener` more than once. Your assumption that they are technically equal was too rash.

Comment: To the OP, you might be interested in Actions, see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html

Comment: @sdasdadas Thanks, I've gone through those a little bit, but am going to be devoting some more time to them. I'm still fairly new to Java.

Comment: The question most certainly has merit, but it is not an appropriate question for SO. That doesn't mean it's a bad question, it simply means it belongs on a mailing list or another forum.

Comment: I had no intention of starting a whole thing over this. I had no intention of procuring an opinion as an answer or endorsing my own. I, as someone new to both Java and SO, wanted an answer to a question from people who share such information. I apologize if that was interpreted as something so unworthy.

Comment: @JasonC I was just addressing your statement about them being equivalent. They aren't, really.

Comment: @JeremyJohnson Much better. If the marked answer to your question does not cover the questions you are now asking in your post, you may wish to unmark it so that more attention is drawn to this question. Up to you.

Comment: @JasonC I'm sure I'll take that into consideration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there are three ways

- `aButton.addActionListener(this);` in the case that class declarations contains `implements ActionListener` and there is `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {` too

f.i. pseudocode

```
public class ButtonDemo implements ActionListener{

    aButton.addActionListener(this);    

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object source = e.getSource();
        if (source == aButton) {

        } 
    }
}
```

- `aButton.addActionListener(new ButtonPress());` is in the case that ActionLIstener is declared as separate class

f.i. pseudocode

```
public class ButtonDemo {    
     aButton.addActionListener(new ButtonPress());
}

public class ButtonPress implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }
}
```

- simpler, clear and without side effects (a.m. two ways)  is to create inner anonymous listener

f.i. pseudocode

```
    aButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: What happens if we say `aButton.addActionListener(new ButtonDemo()));`, instead of `this` in the first example?

Comment: new ButtonDemo() will be listener for event from aButton, and inner public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { never will be used for events from aButton

Answer (score 2):

If you use `this`, then in order for `this` to handle ActionEvents from multiple sources you need to add logic to check the source or command string of the action. This is perfectly reasonable.

If you use other classes, then you can use ActionListeners that are implemented elsewhere, or reuse ones that were designed for a specific common purpose, or define e.g. anonymous inner classes inline which may be convenient in your situation. This is also perfectly reasonable.

Do not think in terms of "advantages" or "disadvantages" -- this is such a common mistake (Is it "bad" to do xyz? Is xyz "good practice"?). You use whatever makes the most sense for your situation and provides the clearest, most maintainable, properly functioning code. Have common sense, be familiar with the language you are working in and the options available, make sane judgments. A language is a way to express an idea, speak (type) clearly.

Comment: Please explain down vote constructively, answer contains some advantages and disadvantages of each and is correct. Down votes out of spite are inappropriate and serve only to confuse a reader.

Answer (score 1):

I guess one disadvantage of using the inner class implementation is that the listener cannot be reused for other buttons , in case, they should have the same listener.
Something like this :

[Can you use the same OnClickListener for different buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133236/can-you-use-the-same-onclicklistener-for-different-buttons)