# Android Expandable Menu Items

Tags: java, android

Im trying to design a menu in which you can connect your social media accounts with my app. To do so, I want a Menu which list all accessable social media apps. 
Eg.:

- Twitter
- Facebook
- Youtube
- etc.

To connect to your account you can click one of the menu items and an individual "content" should appear. I found a way that works like charm but generates a huge overload of code as seen here:

```
 // Twitter
    btn_login_twitter = view.findViewById(R.id.twitter_login_btn);
    img_ca_twitter_expand = view.findViewById(R.id.ca_twitter_expand);
    fl_ca_twitter_content = view.findViewById(R.id.ca_twitter_content_layout);
    fl_ca_twitter_header = view.findViewById(R.id.ca_twitter_header);
    fl_ca_twitter_header.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (fl_ca_twitter_content.getVisibility()== View.VISIBLE) fl_ca_twitter_content.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            else fl_ca_twitter_content.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            img_ca_twitter_expand.animate().rotation(img_ca_twitter_expand.getRotation() == 0 ? 180 : 0).setDuration(500).start();
        }
    });
    // Facebook
    btn_login_facebook = view.findViewById(R.id.facebook_login_btn);
    fl_ca_facebook_content = view.findViewById(R.id.ca_facebook_content_layout);
    img_ca_facebook_expand = view.findViewById(R.id.ca_facebook_expand);
    fl_ca_facebook_header = view.findViewById(R.id.ca_facebook_header);
    fl_ca_facebook_header.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (fl_ca_facebook_content.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) fl_ca_facebook_content.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            else fl_ca_facebook_content.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            img_ca_facebook_expand.animate().rotation(img_ca_facebook_expand.getRotation() == 0 ? 180 : 0).setDuration(500).start();


        }
    });

    //Youtube
    fl_ca_youtube_content = view.findViewById(R.id.ca_youtube_content_layout);
    fl_ca_youtube_header = view.findViewById(R.id.ca_youtube_header);
    img_ca_youtube_expand = view.findViewById(R.id.ca_youtube_expand);
    fl_ca_youtube_header.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (fl_ca_youtube_content.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) fl_ca_youtube_content.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            else fl_ca_youtube_content.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            img_ca_youtube_expand.animate().rotation(img_ca_youtube_expand.getRotation() == 0 ? 180 : 0).setDuration(500).start();


        }
    });
```

As you can see here it is pretty much the same code for every application. Only the name of the attributes changes as the application changes.
Here is a screenshot of how it looks like now
[image: Social Media Expandable List]

Same problem in the xml file:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/ca_scrollview_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/ca_twitter_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/about_twitter_color"
        android:outlineProvider="bounds">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="Twitter"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ca_twitter_expand"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/baseline_keyboard_arrow_down_black_48" />
    </FrameLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ca_twitter_content_layout"
        android:visibility="gone">
        <include layout="@layout/connect_twitter_layout" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/ca_facebook_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/about_facebook_color">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="Facebook"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:id="@+id/ca_facebook_expand"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/baseline_keyboard_arrow_down_black_48" />
    </FrameLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ca_facebook_content_layout"
        android:visibility="gone">
        <include layout="@layout/connect_facebook_layout" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/ca_youtube_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/about_youtube_color">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="Youtube"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ca_youtube_expand"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/baseline_keyboard_arrow_down_black_48" />
    </FrameLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ca_youtube_content_layout"
        android:visibility="gone">
        <include layout="@layout/connect_youtube_layout" />
    </FrameLayout>




</LinearLayout>
```

Is there a better way to solve my problem? I think this one isn't quite nice.

Answer (score 0):

You can improve the code by having a single OnClickListener for clickable items. Please have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133236/can-you-use-the-same-onclicklistener-for-different-buttons) for a detailed explanation.